# Accessing values in an Nx2 matrix of Strings in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following:

```
var data = Array[Array[String]]()

data :+= Array("item1", "")
data :+= Array("item2", "")
data :+= Array("item3", "")
```

I would like to somehow access the second element (the value lets say) of a certain "key" in `data`. I have to do this right now:

```
data(2)(1) = "test"
```

But I would like to do it without having to worry about indexes, something where I can just call the "key" and modify the value, like `data("item1") = "test"`.

Unfornately I do have to use this matrix Array of Strings, which is obviously not optimal, but this is what I have to work with. How do I do this with my datastructure?

Also if I was to change datastructure, what Scala datastrucure would be the best? (I am considering changing it, but unlikely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Map`

```
  val items = mutable.Map("foo" -> "bar", "bar" -> "bat")
  items.update("foo", "baz")
```

If you have to stick with array, something like this will work

```
  data.find(_.head == "foo").foreach { _(1) = "baz" }
```

You can make it look like a function call with a little implicit trickery:

```
  object ArrayAsMap {
     implicit class Wrapper(val it:Array[String]) extends AnyVal {
       def <<-(foo: String) = it(1) = foo
     }

     implicit class Wrapper2(val it: Array[Array[String]]) extends AnyVal {
        def apply(s: String) = Wrapper(it.find(_.head == s).get)
     }
     implicit def toarray(w: Wrapper) = w.it
  }
```

Now, you can write that assignment like:

```
  import ArrayAsMap._
  data("foo") <<- "bar"
```

A few things about this:

- the approach you are using is *really* bad: not only you have to scan the entire array to find the key every time, you are also making implicit assumptions about the contents of the (outer) array, which is especially bad because it is mutable. Something like this `data("foo") = Array.empty` will cause that code to crash badly at runtime.
- you should avoid using mutable state (`var`) and mutable containers (like `Array` or `mutable.Map` ... `Arrays` are kinda inevitable legacy from java, but you should not normally mutate them). Code that uses immutable and referentially transparent statements is much easier to read, maintain and reason about, and much less error-prone. 99% of real-life use cases in scala do not require mutable state if implemented correctly. So, it might be a good idea for you to just pretend that `vars` and mutable containers do not exist at all, and you cannot change any value once it is assigned, until you have learned enough scala to be able to tell that 1% of cases when mutation is really necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough response. The little hack will work, but in the end I think it would be much better for me to reconsider datastructures, which seems to be hard for me, but I will ask another question about it soon since it relates more to Apache Spark.